# Getting error .htaccess: <IfModule not allowed here

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am setting up a local site on my mac Mavericks.  When I do it I get a 500 error.  The logs show me the error in the ".htaccess: IfModule not allowed here".  From everything I have seen it says to put AllowOverride ALL to fix this issue but it is not working for me.  I know I am just missing something simple so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Below is my conf file for that vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/Swany/Sites/test/public"
        ServerName test.dev
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.dev-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.dev-access_log" common

        <Directory "/Users/Swany/code/www/test/public">
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If I delete the .htaccess I get the home page just fine but if I got to any other page I get a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I also needed to go into the default conf file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and also switch AlloOveride All and Require all granted and it started to work.  I thought the vhost conf file would override it but apparently not.